# How to set Safari Selenium WebDriver user agent in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest, safaridriver

I am creating a Safari WebDriver instance with:

```
import selenium.webdriver
driver = webdriver.Safari()
```

Now I'd like to set a custom user agent for the browser. I have noticed that the Safari constructor accepts service_args that selenium service.py file sends further like this:

```
def command_line_args(self):
        return ["-p", "%s" % self.port] + self.service_args
```

But there is lack of documentation on how to properly set a user agent for the Safari webdriver in Python. How to set the user agent?